# Spring boot application Start up error

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am working on spring boot application when running this from console I am getting the below error. Please help me in resolving this. In IDE I am not able to see exception also only command line generating this stack trace. Tried working with different java update (8u121,8u131,8u144) .

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/PersistenceContext
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1116) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1060) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:202) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:702) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:527) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.3.RELEASE]
        at com.websystique.springboot.SpringBootCRUDApp.main(SpringBootCRUDApp.java:15) [classes!/:1.0.0]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [SpringBootCRUDApplicationExample-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [SpringBootCRUDApplicationExample-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) [SpringBootCRUDApplicationExample-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51) [SpringBootCRUDApplicationExample-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/PersistenceContext
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.<clinit>(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:172) ~[spring-orm-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:142) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:89) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1108) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.PersistenceContext
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:94) ~[SpringBootCRUDApplicationExample-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        ... 32 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid distance too far back
        at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.ZipInflaterInputStream.read(ZipInflaterInputStream.java:52) ~[SpringBootCRUDApplicationExample-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
        at sun.misc.Resource.getBytes(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        ... 39 common frames omitted
```

POM.XML

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.websystique.springboot</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringBootCRUDApplicationExample</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>SpringBootCRUDApplicationExample</name>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <h2.version>1.4.187</h2.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Add typical dependencies for a web application -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Add freemarker template support -->        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-freemarker</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Add JPA support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Add Hikari Connection Pooling support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Add H2 database support [for running with local profile] -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>${h2.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Add MySQL database support [for running with PRODUCTION profile] -->       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin><!-- Include if you want to make an executable jar[FAT JAR which 
                    includes all dependencies along with sprinboot loader] that you can run on 
                    commandline using java -jar NAME -->
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Also please look into above POM xml and update me if I am missing any dependencies. Same code is working fine on other machine

Comment: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/PersistenceContext` means that there are some missing dependencies.  could you share your pom.xml, please verify that all the dependencies of your project are present on your pom.xml.  Are you using maven or gradle?

Comment: I have updated POM.xml . Please look into that.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try with this pom.xml in order to use the `1.5.4.RELEASE` version of Spring boot and the current version of h2 database, make sure that all the dependencies are downloaded before restart your application, if you are using eclipse also make sure to update the maven repository to the project.  Hope it help.  There are many dependencies so it takes time in order to download all of them properly.  The parent entry should looks like this:

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
```

Some additional information here: in order to make the [SpringBootCRUDApp](http://websystique.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-angularjs-spring-data-jpa-crud-app-example/) project ready to work you can use `1.4.x` or `1.5.x` Spring boot releases, just make sure that all the dependencies have been downloaded properly from Maven otherwise the `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` will be thrown.

After all the dependencies are properly downloaded there is something interesting that happens with Spring boot `1.4.x` because there is a new error when the code is executed called `java.lang.IllegalStateException: required key [datasource.sampleapp.hibernate.dialect] not found`

Why is that?: it is because of how are listed the available profiles on the `application.yml` properties file.

```
spring:
  profiles: local, default
```

The error is raised because the blank space after the coma, in order to correct it just delete the blank space (only when Spring Boot `1.4.x` is used)

```
spring:
  profiles: local,default
```

and it happens because the value

`" default"` is not detected as a defult profile because Spring boot is expecting a `"default"` with out the blank space, this behavior only happens with SB `1.4.x`

Why in Spring boot `1.5x` there is no error? well it is because of some good enhancements that has been made to the configuration process in order to read properly the spring.profiles property and avoid the problem when there is a blank space after coma, actually that could happen only when there are many profiles but no one is active and also there is no a `default` profile detected.

Comment: Its working now. Thanks a lot. I have been struggling with this from last two days. Could you please explain why it was working fine on other machine with the Old POM? I am new to spring boot

Comment: sure why not. your pom.xml gives me very good information even that you were trying to practice this tutorial http://websystique.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-angularjs-spring-data-jpa-crud-app-example/ so I get the entire code and find out that this tutorial is using a application.yml and that feature was not working correctly with the 1.4.3.RELEASE, it sometimes happens because the maven repositories changes when is an old release, in that case the best solution is to use a current version.

Comment: Actually if you go to https://start.spring.io/ you can see that there is no `1.4.3.RELEASE` listed as an option to create a spring boot app.

Comment: im doing some aditional research to find out the root cause i&#39;ll let you know as soon as i get the results.

Comment: Just added new information, hope it help if you find an error like that.